# Entity Framework Linq query returning incorrect value for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have a Query:

```
    var cams = (from c in db.cameras
                        join s in db.camera_sites on c.camera_site_id equals s.id
                        join o in db.servers on s.server_id equals o.id
                        where (c.enabled == "yes"
                        && s.enabled == "yes"
                        && o.enabled == "yes" 
                        && o.type == "hosted"
                        && o.server_method == "webservices"
                        && c.account_id == accountId)
                        select new EventCamera_Named { Camera = c, SiteName = s.name, ServerName = o.name }).ToList();
```

The problem is the SiteName that is selected is the same as Camera.name

The sql that is generated is:

```
    SELECT
    `Filter1`.`id`, 
    `Filter1`.`account_id`, 
    `Filter1`.`camera_site_id`, 
    `Filter1`.`enabled`, 
    `Filter1`.`name`, 
    ...,
    `Filter1`.`name` AS `name1`, 
    `Extent3`.`name` AS `name2`

    FROM (SELECT
    `Extent1`.`id`, 
    `Extent1`.`account_id`, 
    `Extent1`.`camera_site_id`, 
    `Extent1`.`enabled`, 
    `Extent1`.`name`, 
    ..., 
    `Extent2`.`id` AS `id1`, 
    `Extent2`.`account_id` AS `account_id1`, 
    `Extent2`.`server_id`, 
    ...
    FROM `cameras` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `camera_sites` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`camera_site_id` = `Extent2`.`id`
    WHERE ('yes' = `Extent1`.`enabled`) AND ('yes' = `Extent2`.`enabled`)) AS `Filter1` INNER JOIN `servers` AS `Extent3` ON `Filter1`.`server_id` = `Extent3`.`id`
    WHERE ((('yes' = `Extent3`.`enabled`) AND ('hosted' = `Extent3`.`type`)) AND ('webservices' = `Extent3`.`server_method`)) AND (`Filter1`.`account_id` = 39884476)
```

How can I rewrite my query return the correct values and what is causing it to get confused?

Comment: Does it select `Extent2.name` in the inner select clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I moved the `enabled` check directly after the db it was referencing the sql it generated was correct.

```
    var cams = (from c in db.cameras 
                    where c.enabled == "yes"
                    join s in db.camera_sites on c.camera_site_id equals s.id 
                    where s.enabled == "yes"
                    join o in db.servers on s.server_id equals o.id
                    where (o.enabled == "yes" 
                    && o.type == "hosted"
                    && o.server_method == "webservices"
                    && c.account_id == accountId)
                    select new EventCamera_Named { Camera = c, SiteName = s.name, ServerName = o.name }).ToList();
```